# Passar variavel jquery no nome do arquivo - como se fosse get

Tags: javascript, jquery

Holá, pessoal, não estou conseguindo informações sobre isso pois não sei como procurar, tentei pegar variavel jquery, e coisas do tipo e não retornou o que preciso.

É o seguinte: preciso passar uma variavel em js no nome do arquivo e dentro desse arquivo pegar essa variavel:

Ex:

```
<script src='app.translator.js?lang=pt_BR'></script>
```

dentro do arquivo 'app.translator.js' como eu pego essa variavel 'lang'??

```
var lang = ????????;
```

============editado daqui para baixo com uma resposta=========================

Quero deixar aqui outra solução que consegui

```
<script src='app.translator.js'></script>   
//conteudo do arquivo
var appTranslate = function(){
    var formLogin = function(lang){
        //minha funcao com a lang carregada aqui...
    };
    return {
        init: function(lang){
            alert(lang);
            // passo a lang para minha funcao
            formLogin(lang);
        },
    };
}();
```

apos carregar o app.translator.js no footer da pagina html, apenas chamei a funcao

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='app.translator.js'></script>
<script>
$(function(){
// vai mostrar o alert('pt_BR')
appTranslate.init('pt_BR');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('lang'),
    param = el.getAttribute('src').match(/lang=([^]*)/)[1];
alert(param);
```

```html
<script id='lang' src='app.translator.js?lang=pt_BR'></script>
```

Comment: Quero deixar claro que esta resposta serviu exatamente para o que queria. porem achei outra solução e editei a pergunta com a resposta. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Opa dentro do translator.js você pode capturar o valor usando jquery assim:

Declare seu script assim:

```
<script src='app.translator.js' lang='pt_BR' parametro='teste'></script>  
var variaveis = $('script[src*=app.translator.js]');
```

tendo o elemento pode-se caputarar assim (dentro do translator.js):

```
alert(variaveis.attr('lang'));
```

Comment: +1 Opa, gostei da solução.

Comment: @Guerra Não funcionou pra mim aqui, tem como fazer um exemplo funcional no https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Sergio, cara nem me dei conta de passar a variavel dessa maneira, fiz aqui e deu certo.     appTranslator.init('pt_BR');   dentro do meu app.translator.js ficou assim: 

var appTranslate = function(){
    return {
        init: function(lang){
         alert(lang);
        },
    };
}();